# How long should it take to install Win Server 2008 R2 on a virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtualization, windows-server-2008

I have a server running Ubuntu 11.10 and am trying to install Windows Server 2008 R2 into a virtual machine.  I gave the VM 3 gigs of Ram and the processor is an intel dual core Celeron ~2.5 GHz.

The installer has been "unpacking files" for over an hour and its only 45% done.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

Since you posted this an hour ago, that makes it two hours. Did it finish installing? I've found that VM I/O is fairly slow and could certainly be the cause for the install taking a while. It's unpacking several gigabytes of data into a virtual hard drive that has to keep expanding it's size on the disk. You might get better performance if you pre-allocate the virtual hard drive space before the installation.

Comment: It ended up taking 4 hours then crashed.  The virtual hd is preallocated.  I'll try reformatting everything and re-downloading the Win 2008 image.  Thanks for the idea though!